# Replacing for loop in pandas Python search and replace

Tags: python, performance

I have 2 pandas dataframes. I want to do a find and replace between 2 dataframes. In the `df_find` dataframe, in the current_title column, i want to search in every row for any occurrence of values from '`keywrod`' column in the `df_replace` dataframe and if found replace it with corresponding value from '`keywordlength`' column.

I have been able to get rid of the loop for `df_find` dataframe since i need to iterate over every row in this dataframe by using `str.replace` which is a vectorized form of replace function.

Performance matters in my case, as both the dataframes run into GB's. So, i want to get rid of the loop for `df_replace` here and use any other efficient way of iterating through all rows of `df_replace` dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df_find = pd.read_csv("input_find.csv")
df_replace = pd.read_csv("input_replace.csv")

#replace
for i,j in zip(df_replace.keyword,df_replace.keywordLength):
    df_find.current_title=df_find.current_title.str.replace(i,j,case=False)
```

df_replace This dataframe has the data we need for find and replace

```
keyword       keywordLength
IT Manager    ##10##
Sales Manager ##13##
IT Analyst    ##12##
Store Manager ##13##
```

df_find is where we need to do the transformation.

Before executing find and replace code:

```
current_title
I have been working here as a store manager since after I passed from college
I am sales manager and primarily work in the ASEAN region. My primary rolw is to bring new customers.
I initially joined as a IT analyst and because of my sheer drive and dedication, I was promoted to IT manager position within 3 years
```

After executing find and replace through above code

```
current_title
I have been working here as a ##13## since after I passed from college
I am ##13## and primarily work in the ASEAN region. My primary rolw is to bring new customers.
I initially joined as a ##12## and because of my sheer drive and dedication, I was promoted to ##10## position within 3 years
```